# How to print Zebra byte array to a printer?

Tags: java, printing, zebra-printers

I programmed in Java to send byte array (Zebra type) to a printer to print. I want to have the printer dialog pop up. I googled and see people using `printerjob`, but I never see how the byte array data being sent cause they just have `printerjob.print();` .

I also tried to use `PrintService[] services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);`
 to get printer to print, but it didn't return any printserivce to me when I debug in Intellij (I have networked printer).

Right now, I would like to have the printerjob (1st way) to print my byte array if I can. Otherwise, can some one also point out why 2nd way didn't give me any printservice and how to fix it?

Either way will be great to me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read through the docs yet? (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/print/PrinterJob.html)

Comment: @Tezra, Could you give a little more detail, please?